Mongoose query on an array field with multiple items no longer working
I recently upgraded from Mongoose 5.x to 8.x and one of my queries that previously worked is no longer returning any documents, and nothing in the migration guides seemed to indicate why that would be the case.
Here is a reduced/simplified example of one of the collection items from our fixture data:
{
    _id: ObjectId('5ff8c2dd6b59a6000d7bfdb2'),
    __t: 'Item',
    name: 'Item Name',
    tags: {
      tag1: [
        'option1',
        'option2',
        'option3',
      ],
      tag2: [
        'option1',
      ],
    },
  },
 

My query looks something like this:
{"$and":[{"$and":[{"tags.tag1":["option2"]},{"tags.tag2":["option1"]}]}

In Mongoose 5.x, the fixture document above would be returned from this query. However in 8.x, it is not. I tested a bunch of things and it turns out if I were to remove option1 and option3 such that the new tags object looked like this:
tags: {
      tag1: [
        'option2',
      ],
      tag2: [
        'option1',
      ],
    },

then the item does get returned from the query. This seems to indicate that it will only be returned if the tag1 array matches the query exactly, rather than simply containing the item requested.
How would one ask Mongoose to return the document if the tag1 array includes option2, even if there are other tags in the array?

use $in https://mongoplayground.net/p/RQx2MJFivIK

Use $setIsSubset for comparison of 2 arrays.
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          [
            "option2"
          ],
          "$tags.tag1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          [
            "option1"
          ],
          "$tags.tag2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})

Mongo Playground

I get this error when I try this: "MongoServerError", message: "unknown top level operator: $setIsSubset" }

Not sure if relevant, but all the query logic is being sent from the frontend, as the endpoints are being generated by express-restify-mongoose

@ipenguin67 what is your DB version? That error is likely caused by an old version of DB that is yet to support the function

This is a detailed answer to the question. There is a short answer already posted separately. Request you may please start from there and proceed with this if not doing so.
There are two things to note - array match and value match. The following action log will demonstrate it.
use test
test> t = db.test
test> t.drop();

test> t.insertOne({a:[1]});

// open query
test> t.find();
[ { a: [ 1 ] } ]

// below query finds the document by an exact match or an array match
test> t.find({a: [1] });
[ { a: [ 1 ] } ]

// below query finds the document by a value match
test> t.find({a:1});
[ { a: [ 1 ] } ]

// note that the array now has two items by the following query
test> t.updateOne({},{$push:{a:2}});
test> t.find();
[ { a: [ 1, 2 ] } ]


// below query still finds the document by a value match
test> t.find({a:1});
[ { a: [ 1, 2 ] } ]

// below query does not find the document by an exact match or array match since [1 ] not equal to [1, 2]
test> t.find({a:[1]});
<no documents>

// below query does find the document by an exact match or a array match since [1,2 ]  equal to [1, 2]
test> t.find({a:[1,2]});
[ { a: [ 1, 2 ] } ]

// below query does not find the document by an exact match or a array match since [2,1 ] not equal to [1, 2]
test> t.find({a:[1,2]});
[ { a: [ 1, 2 ] } ]


The issue is with the given values - [“option2”] and [“option1”].
In this case, it should be simply string values like “option2” and “option1”.
The modified query would be like this:
t.issue.find({"$and":[{"$and":[{"tags.tag1":"option2"},{"tags.tag2":"option1"}]}]})

OUTPUT:
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('5ff8c2dd6b59a6000d7bfdb2'),
    __t: 'Item',
    name: 'Item Name',
    tags: { tag1: [ 'option1', 'option2', 'option3' ], tag2: [ 'option1' ] }
  }
]


$in operator is used to perform match a single value against array
As mentioned above please try executing query as mentioned in following link
https://mongoplayground.net/p/RQx2MJFivIK
